# What should the indexing strategy be to support queries that are a combination of different fields?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Lets say I have a User collection, where a document looks like this

> {
>     "name": "Starlord",
>     "age": 24,
>     "gender": "Male",
>     "height": 180,
>     "weight": 230,
>     "hobbies": "Flying Spaceships"
>   }

Now, I want someone to be able to search for User based on one or more of these fields. So I add a compound index containing all these fields in the order above.

The issue is that MongoDB indexing works great when the query fields are a prefix of the indexed fields. For example, if I query by `name`, `age` and `gender` then the performance of the query is great. If I query by `name`, `gender` and `weight`, then the performance of the query is not so great (although it still uses the index and is faster than no-index).

What indexing strategy do you use when you have a use case like this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue regarding the indexing strategy?

Comment: I realized that MongoDB wasn't the right tool for this use case and decided to use Elasticsearch

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, ElasticSearch is pretty awesome. I'm glad that you were able to fix the issue you were facing.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your query by `name`, `age` and `gender` works great while the query by `name`, `gender` and `weight` does not is because the order of the fields matter significantly for compound indexes in MongoDB, especially the index's prefixes. As explained in [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) in the documentation, a compound index can support queries on any prefix of its fields. So assuming you created the index in the order you presented the fields, the query for `name`, `age` and `gender` is a prefix of your compound index, while `name`, `gender` and `weight` can only take advantage of the `name` part of the index.

Supporting all possible combinations of queries on these fields would require you to create enough compound indexes so that all possible queries are prefixes of your indexes. I would say that this is not something you would want to do. Since your question asks about indexing strategies for queries with multiple fields, I would suggest that you look into the specific data access patterns that are most useful for your data set and create a few compound indexes that support these, taking advantage of the prefixes concept and omitting certain fields with low cardinality from the index, such as `gender`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to query for all combinations, the number of indexes requires explodes quickly. The feature that comes to the rescue is called ["index intersection"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/).

Create a simple index on each field and trust the query optimizer to perform the correct index intersection. This feature is relatively new (from 2.6) and not as feature complete as in the well-known RBDMSses. It makes sense to track the [Jira Ticket for index intersections](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071) to know the limitations, because the limitations are quite severe. It usually makes sense to carefully mix simple indexes (that can be intersected) and compound indexes (for very common queries).

In your specific case, you can utilize the fact that many fields are numeric and the range of valid values is very limited (e.g., for age, height and weight). The `gender` field has low selectivity and shouldn't be indexed in any case. Filter the gender in the last step, because it will, on average, only double the amount of data that must be processed.

Creating `n!` compound indexes is almost certainly not an option for `n > 3`...

Comment: Unfortunately, index intersection works only for the intersection of 2 indexes in MongoDB 2.6. So if I had individual indexes for each of them and my query included the fields `name` and `age`, then it would work. However, if it included `name`, `age` and `gender` - it would not work.

Comment: True. I updated the answer a bit. In the end, there's no one-size-fits-all solution for this problem at present.